# Avoiding loss of mysql data when script terminated abruptly by server crash or run-time limit

Tags: mysql, updates

Before converting a project to use mysql, I have questions regarding the best way to avoid loss of a simple record update due to either a server  crash or a program shutdown due to exceeding a/the cgi run-time limit.

My project is public and therefore applicable to any / many hosts where high level server side management isn't an option.

I wish to open a list file (or table) and acquire a list of records to parse one at a time.

While parsing each acquired list record, have the program / script perform a task with each record and update a counter (simple table) upon successful completion of each task (alternatively update each record with a success flag).

Do mysql tables get auto updated to the hard drive when "updated" or "added" to, thus, avoiding loss of all table changes to the point of crash if / when the program / script is violently terminated as described?

To have any chance with and do same with simple text files the counter has to be opened and closed for each update (as all content of open files on most O/S get clobbered when crashed).

Any description outline of mysql commands / processes etc to follow, if needed to avoid described losses, would also be very much appreciated.

Also, if any sugestions, are they applicable to both InnoDB and MyISM?

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer comes to mind: SQL TRANSACTIONS. They're like a stack of SQL commands that 1. have to be "commited" 2. would come into action only if the last command is successfully executed.

I think this would help:
http://www.sqlteam.com/article/introduction-to-transactions

If my answer wasn't correct, pls, let me know if i misunderstood your intensions.